# Careers - Can't apply to a position online - Javascript error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I want to apply to a position online using my Stack Careers 2.0 profile, but I can't due to a Javascript error.
It's pretty frustrating as the job was posted yesterday and I wanted to be quick.

Page:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/15096/software-developer-lightfire-studios?a=hPOFboc

When I click the button to apply online, Firebug tells me:

```
e is undefined
[Break On This Error] (function(){$(function(){h();o();l();t...e,b.last_delay)},b.last_delay)}})})();

http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/jobs.min.js?345fca (line 1)
```

Comment: We're looking into this

Comment: The successful applicant shouldn't be deterred by a mere javascript error :)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the problem and thanks for letting us know, this is resolved now.